# how to update content page from master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Menu links are in the master page and and the corresponding click events are written in the master page itself. I have only one content page. Data is saved in html form in the DB and that will be rendered to the content page on corresponding menu link clicks. But the problem is content page load occurs before the master page so the content page is blank. Here my code-

```
public void GetLinkPage(Int32 linkId)//master page
{
    LinkContentEnitity linkContent = new LinkContentEnitity();
    linkContent = PageController.GetPageContent(linkId);              
}
```

`linkContent` contains that content page in HTML form. How can I print this value on content page?

Comment: Can you show the Page_Load for both the Master and Content as well as the event handler for the click event please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's not entirely clear, it sounds like you are saying your content page needs information in its own Load event that is generated in the `Page_Load` event of the master page?

So either move the code that calls `GetPageLink()` to `PreRender` in your content page, or add an event handler in ContentPage for `Page_LoadComplete()` (which fires after all child controls on a page are loaded) and call `GetPageLink()` and do your rendering from there, e.g. in content page:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
}
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // do stuff here, instead of OnLoad/Page_Load event
}
```

By the way this is a useful reference for event order. The problem you are having is very easy to get into when dealing with nested controls (master/content, usercontrols, etc), it helps to have a good understanding of the event order.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it might be this... On your content page, add a public method that does the work you need done.  In the master page, cast this.Page to your page class and call that method.